# Web.Config Error - Accessing MySQL Database on GoDaddy

Tags: mysql, web-config

Attempting to connect to a remote (GoDaddy) MySQL database I have created under a domain I own.  I am using c#, and not php.

The IP address in the web.config is provided by GoDaddy in Plesk.

Receiving the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '[UserProfile]([UserId] int NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, [Email] nvarchar(56) N' at line 1
```

This is my web.config (and associated connection string):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.data>
  </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Server=50.62.209.107;Port=3306;Database=RP;Uid=my_userid;Pwd=my_password" name="RP" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></add>
        <add connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=RP;Uid=my_userid;Pwd=my_password" name="RP_Local" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></add>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am able to use those same parameters in MySQL Workbench and access the database with no problem.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<add name="connstring" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=marctest;password=PASSWORD" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```